# Append symbol with jquery showing invalid symbol

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, symbols

I tried to append a text which includes this symbol: » but it doesn't work with JQuery for some reason. Any workaround this?

the script:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.six .ovh .entry-content a').hide();
jQuery('.six .ovh .entry-content').each(function() {
    var href   = jQuery(this).prev('header').find('h2 > a').attr('href'),
        anchor = jQuery('<a />', {href: href, text: ' Continue reading »'});

//    jQuery(this).append(anchor);
    jQuery('p:last-child', this).append(anchor);
});

    });
</script
```

here how it shows it:

Continue reading �

Comment: What doesn't work? [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/AfJu5/)

Comment: @brbcoding check out my script I edited my question

Comment: Probably encoding then.

Comment: html encoding is UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

replace » with `&raquo;` and you should be good

Comment: I tried that before but it didnt work, it showed the $raquo ;

Comment: it's `&raquo;`. no dollar sign and no space before the ;

Comment: yes @v1cious I know, I just typed that by mistake the dollar sign.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I just changed the anchor variable from text to html